# How to catch unserialize exception?

Tags: php, serialization, try-catch

Is it possible to catch an exception on PHP when `unserialize()` generates an error?

Answer (score 18):

A simple way is:

```
$ret = @unserialize($foo);
if($ret === null){
   //Error case
}
```

But it isn't the most modern solution.

The best way is as mentioned before to have a custom error/exception handler (not only for this case). But depending of what you are doing it may be overkill.

Comment: per documentation：In case the passed string is not unserializeable, FALSE is returned. Luckily few ones would do `serialize(false)`

Comment: "In case the passed string is not unserializeable, FALSE is returned **and E_NOTICE is issued**." An E_ is thrown as well.

Comment: The `@` symbol is needed for this solution, because otherwise PHP will give a notice on screen when unserialize fails.

Comment: This is not a good answer. The originally serialized value might have been null. `serialize(NULL)` is `"N;"` which unserializes to `NULL`. Nobody serializes null under most conditions, but this could happen in some complex, automated system or computation -- e.g., the output of a halting problem calculation (where NULL is not the same thing as FALSE).

Comment: you need to modify check to at least

`if($foo!="N;" && $ret === null){
   //Error case
}`

Thus you know that source variable was not null, so null was returned as an error.

Comment: I modified the code in order to use it: 
$ret = unserialize($foo);
if($ret === false){
   /* Error case */
}

Comment: Since return is false when unserializeable, code should be
`if(($ret === false) and ($foo!='b:0;')) {...}`

Answer (score 17):

No, you can't catch it, `unserialize()` does not throw Exception.

*In case the passed string is not unserializeable, FALSE is returned and E_NOTICE is issued.*

you can set a custom Exception handler to handle all errors:

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");
```

Answer (score 6):

A full solution would look like the following:

```
<?php
// As mentioned in the top answer, we need to set up 
// some general error handling
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");


// Note, there are two types of way it could fail, 
// the fail2 fail is when try to unserialise just 
// false, it should fail. Also note, what you 
// do when something fails is up to your app. 
// So replace var_dump("fail...") with your 
// own app logic for error handling
function unserializeSensible($value) {
    $caught = false;
    try {
        $unserialised = unserialize($value);
    } catch(ErrorException $e) {
        var_dump("fail");
        $caught = true;
    }
    // PHP doesn't have a try .. else block like Python
    if(!$caught) {
        if($unserialised === false && $value !== serialize(false)) {
            var_dump("fail2");
        } else {
            var_dump("pass");
            return $unserialised;
        }
    }
}

unserializeSensible('b:0;'); // Should pass
unserializeSensible('b:1;'); // Should pass
unserializeSensible('a:2:{s:1:"a";b:0;s:1:"b";s:3:"foo";}'); // Should pass
unserializeSensible('a:2:{s:1:"a";b:0;s:1:"b";s:3:1111111111111111;}'); // Should fail
unserializeSensible(123); // Should fail
unserializeSensible("Gday"); // Should fail
unserializeSensible(false); // Should fail2
unserializeSensible(true); // Should fail
```

Answer (score 5):

Convert all PHP errors (warnings notices etc) to exceptions. Example is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php).

Answer (score 4):

As Mihai Iorga explained, `unserialize` does not throw anything. You could check for errors by comparing the return value with `false`, but it will fail if the serialized value is a `false` boolean value. The solution below solves this problem without resorting to slow and cumbersome techniques (such as setting custom error handlers).

The following code throws a `InvalidArgumentException` if the serialized value `$v` is invalid, otherwise `$x` will contain the unserialized value.

Special care is taken to differentiate between:

- `unserialize()` returning `false` to signal an invalid serialized value
- the original value actually being a boolean `false`.

```php
$x = @unserialize ($v);
if ($x === false && $v != 'b:0;')
  throw new InvalidArgumentException;
```

Comment: Everybody knows the `@` character but sometimes we forget the minor knowledges. `@` character prevents the notice, `b:0;` is serialized value of `false`. Your answer is created a lightning struck in my brain :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple function from my CMS EFFCORE:

```
  function data_is_serialized($data) {
    if ($data === 'b:0;') return true;
    if (is_string($data) && @unserialize($data, ['allowed_classes' => ['stdClass']]) !== false) return true;
    return false;
  }
```

Test:

```
var_dump( data_is_serialized(0)     === false );
var_dump( data_is_serialized(1)     === false );
var_dump( data_is_serialized('')    === false );
var_dump( data_is_serialized('0')   === false );
var_dump( data_is_serialized('1')   === false );
var_dump( data_is_serialized(true)  === false );
var_dump( data_is_serialized(false) === false );
var_dump( data_is_serialized([])    === false );

var_dump( data_is_serialized(serialize(0))     === true );
var_dump( data_is_serialized(serialize(1))     === true );
var_dump( data_is_serialized(serialize(''))    === true );
var_dump( data_is_serialized(serialize('0'))   === true );
var_dump( data_is_serialized(serialize('1'))   === true );
var_dump( data_is_serialized(serialize(true))  === true );
var_dump( data_is_serialized(serialize(false)) === true );
var_dump( data_is_serialized(serialize([]))    === true );
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, unserialize was returning blank when it failed, not null.

```
$ret = @unserialize($foo);
if ( ! $ret ) {
   //Error case
}
```